# How to decompress snappy encoded file in Splunk

Tags: prometheus, splunk, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to send metrics from Prometheus to Splunk. By default Prometheus compress using snappy.
But Splunk receives this compressed format.
[image]

I tried to configure Splunk inputs.conf, but no luck.

```
[tcp]
compressed = true

[splunktcp]
compressed = true
```

How to decompress in Splunk?
is it possible to change any other config files to read decompressed data?